# Python expression printing false but passing if

Tags: python, math

[image: Example]

If you see the above picture you’ll see I’ve got a basic multiplication game. I’m printing out true or false depending on whether the answer entered is the same as the correct answer.

You’ll see that or the 12 x 2 question I entered a wrong answer and it printed out False. However my final score was 10 which means it must have passed the IF statement and added 1 to my score.

I have no idea why this happened or how it happens. I am able to replicate it when I enter a wrong answer that is over 100.

Comment: Why a screenshot? Please post the code itself, so that it can be copied and tested.

Comment: Hint: count the number of questions.

Comment: There are 11 questions not 10

Comment: @GPhilo this happened during college and I only have a screenshot till tomorrow. I can type it up when I’m home though.

Comment: Yeah but there shouldn’t be 11 questions asked because of `answered = answered+1`

Comment: There are 11 questions because your whil begins with 0, it has to be `while answered < 10`

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: In this case I didn't downvote (there were enough of those already), but I think the reason is stated in the first comment: "Why a screenshot?"

Comment: Kinda harsh! @Matthias.

Comment: @Shiv: A screenshot is unreadable on smaller displays and possible answerers can't copy and paste the code to test it. Did you check other posts before writing here? Did you read the rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while` loop is executed 11 times. So you really got 10 points out of 11.
Change the `<=` in the loop to `<`.

Answer (score 2):

See you asked 11 question not 10

your program ran from 0 to 10 (total 11 times)

Answer (score 1):

just try changing the last line to something like this:

```
print("You got {0} out of {1}".format(points, answered))
```

This way it always prints out the number of questions answered rather than hardcoding the value (which you hardcoded incorrectly as it happens)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to slightly change you code like this and it will work for you:

```
print("you got" + str(points) + "out of" + answered)
```

and you will see that your answered is not 10 but 11, cus you used

```
while answered <= 10:
```

not

```
answered < 10:
```

which means it will run one more than you need.